# Has Dungeons & Dragons ever been officially translated into Hungarian?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, translations, hungarian

So I was talking with a friend from Budapest, Hungary who told me that he had played *Dungeons & Dragons* back in the 1980s. However, he explained that at the time they were playing "bootlegged" versions because there was no official Hungarian translation.<sup>*</sup> According to him, D&D was seen as a tool of Western influence (being based on Western folklore and glorifying capitalist ideas in that you work to get treasure for yourself, I guess) and with Hungary being a Soviet bloc nation it was banned from import.

Today, Hungary is a democracy like many countries in the former Soviet Bloc. My friend hasn't played D&D for years and he wasn't sure about the current status of the game. He imagines that an English version could be found at some bookstore, but he wasn't sure if it was ever officially available in Hungarian. Was any edition of *Dungeons & Dragons* ever officially released in Hungarian since the fall of the Soviet Union?

*<sup>*</sup> Fun fact: he said that the bootleg Hungarian translation he used had all sorts of amusing errors that he discovered later when he learned English. For instance, Clerics' "Turn Undead" ability used the definition of "Turn" meaning "Turn Into", so for a while they played where clerics had the ability to become undead a limited number of times per day!*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has! The only edition ever officially translated into Hungarian is the original 3rd edition (not 3.5e). RPGGeek lists Hungarian translations of the Player's Handbook ([*Játékosok könyve*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitemversion/197427/jatekosok-konyve)), Dungeon Masters Guide ([*Kalandmesterek könyve*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitemversion/197430/kalandmesterek-konyve)), and Monster Manual ([*Szörnyek könyve*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitemversion/197432/szornyek-konyve)), all published in 2001.

Finding copies might be a trick, but they're out there!

Answer (score 10):

Yep, as @SevenSidedDie says, quite a number of **D&D 3rd edition** books were translated into Hungarian officially from 2000 on, I guess, and they are still available through dedicated book/webshops like [Szellemlovas](http://www.szellemlovas.hu/fantasykonyv/) ("Ghost Rider") -- where your friend could even preorder the books of the [upcoming](http://www.szellemlovas.hu/fantasykonyv/index.php?r=webboltTermekValtozat/view&termek_valtozat_id=13500&uj_termek=1) [5th](http://www.szellemlovas.hu/fantasykonyv/index.php?r=webboltTermekValtozat/view&termek_valtozat_id=13502&uj_termek=1) [edition](http://www.szellemlovas.hu/fantasykonyv/index.php?r=webboltTermekValtozat/view&termek_valtozat_id=13504&uj_termek=1) (in English.)

Here's [a link to the 3.0 PHB](http://www.szellemlovas.hu/fantasykonyv/index.php?r=webboltTermekValtozat/view&termek_valtozat_id=1446&uj_termek=1) in Hungarian in the above-mentioned shop, and here's [the very same shop's D&D tag](http://www.szellemlovas.hu/fantasykonyv/index.php?r=webboltTermekValtozat/index&cimke_id=34), with quite a number of official D&D translations including core rulebooks, novels, settings, etc -- and English originals, of course.

Disclaimer: No, I'm not affiliated with Szellemlovas. I just happen to know someone who knows about them. It's a small world, isn't it?

Comment: Nice. Looks like the 5e stuff they're selling is *Angol nyelvű* ("English") only though, so a Hungarian 5th edition might not be happening. :/

Comment: There are no plans for any translations for 5e at this time, but that might change.

Comment: I can only accept one answer sadly so I chose the one that listed the books available, but I really appreciate the fact that you did the work to track down a place where they can be purchased!

Comment: @Thunderforge No worries, I know how it feels like wanting to accept more than one answer. Also, in fact I practically wrote my answer to support SevenSidedDie's one. :)

Answer (score 2):

As a supplement to the answers about 3rd edition:

As of 2022, there apparently had been plans to publish a Hungarian version of D&D 5th edition, as indicated in [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/ua5u2o/dnd5e_localized_hungarian_edition_officially/). According to the post and as verified in various Hungarian sources, the starter kit had been translated to Hungarian and released, with Hungarian versions of the main books soon to be ready for purchase.

However, due to unknown issues between the various groups, the release was canceled, so the books do not currently seem to be available in Hungarian. Although some people speculated in the comments under the linked post that Wizards of the Coast ran afoul of Hungary's anti-LBGTQ laws, which caused problems with publication, as some other authors have in the past, [this article](https://www.gamestar.hu/valodi-jatekok/lesujto-hir-erkezett-a-dungeons-dragons-5-kiadasanak-magyar-valtozatarol-309702.html) (in Hungarian) suggests that the true cause was a dispute over the rights between WotC and their translation partner, with WotC alleging that the translations were low-quality and trying to cancel the contract.

As such, the books apparently do exist, in the sense that they were written, but are not available for sale.